# When you scroll up on my webpage on a phone there is white on the bottom. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that works fine on web browser, but when I visit the webpage on my phone and scroll my thumb up, I see white content where it shouldn't be.

This is the webpage before touching it:

[image: Here is the webpage when first visiting][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV0Ge.png)

This is webpage when I press the background and move my thumb up:

[image]

As you can see on the second image, at the bottom of the page, there is a white space between the footer and background image.

Here is the css:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
   background-image: url('then.jpg');
   min-height: 100%;

}

  display: block;
    label{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: right;
}
    .form {
       margin: 0 auto;
       margin-top: 40px;
    width:350px;
    height:35%;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
        border: 1px solid;
        box-shadow:5px 10px;


    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: white;
   overflow: hidden;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;

}
    #yourinfo{
        font-size: 35px;
    }
  #nextBttn {


            width:135px;
            height:25px;

        }
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
    filter: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .form a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .form a.icon {
    float: right; 

  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<body >
<div class="background-image"></div>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About Us</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="form">
   <form name="firstForm"method="post"  id="form1" action="http://localhost:8080/connect.php">
       <header id="yourinfo"><b>Your information</b></header><br><br><br>
    <label id="nameLabel">Name:</label><br>
        <input id="nameInput"type="text"><br><br>
        <label id="ageLabel">Age:</label><br>
    <input id="ageInput"type="text" width="55%"><br><br>
    <label id="emailLabel">Email Address:</label><br>
         <input id="emailInput" type = "text"><br><br>
        <label id="phoneLabel">Phone:</label><br>
    <input id="phoneInput" type="text"><br><br>
       <br>
     <input id="nextBttn" type="submit" value="Next">
       <br>
       <br>
    </form>
    </div>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Contact us</a>

</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS for the `body` to include `background-attachment:fixed;`, which should keep the background from scrolling.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('then.jpg');
  background-attachment:fixed;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I added whats in your answer, but get the same result on my mobile phone.